# mysql : select the last action of each user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
ActionTime              UserID        Score
2011-08-15 12:06:00       1              14
2011-08-15 14:45:00       2              17
2011-08-16 12:17:00       1              20   <== select this row
2011-08-16 04:28:00       2              14
2011-08-17 06:52:00       2              16   <== select this row
```

I want to find out the Score and ActionTime of each user in their last action. (as indicated above)

I know I can do it one by one like this:

```
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE UserID=? ORDER BY ActionTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

But we have hundreds of different UserID (and it keeps increasing of course). This will cause large amount of PHP-to-MySQL communications which is unacceptable.

I just wonder if it is possible to get all the rows at once execution / communication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you first query for the maximum ActionTime for each UserID, you can use this as a subquery to select the Score:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM MyTable AS m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(i.ActionTime) ActionTime, i.UserID
  FROM MyTable i
  GROUP BY i.UserID
) AS j ON (j.ActionTime = m.ActionTime AND j.UserID = m.UserID)
```

There is an issue with the above SQL - if the same user has more than 1 row with an identical ActionTime, you will get multiple rows for that user. If you decide you want the Maximum score in that case, you can do:

```
SELECT m.ActionTime, m.UserID, MAX(m.Score) Score
FROM MyTable AS m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(i.ActionTime) ActionTime, i.UserID
  FROM MyTable i
  GROUP BY i.UserID
) AS j ON (j.ActionTime = m.ActionTime AND j.UserID = m.UserID)
GROUP BY m.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30743971/7718073

Works for me, pretty simple solution. MAX() will work with timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * from MyTable Group by UserId ORDER BY ActionTime DESC

Comment: ORDER BY is applied to the result set after the GROUP BY clause - it cannot change the result set, only re-order it, so cannot ensure that the ActionTime chosen is the latest one, or that the score chosen matches it.